# clean react native project immediately crashes on real android device debug mode

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, npm

I have a strange problem with React Native. I have checked it with several versions of RN for example 0.55.0 to 0.61.2 and tried several solutions but none of them solved my problem.
The problem is when I install debug apk on my real device(samsung s7 edge - android 8.0.0), when the bundle load, app immediately crashes. But if I install signed release apk, it works fine. It is so wired.

For example I did:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

Then app crashed immediately, Though it works properly on emulator.

here is logcat logs:

```
10-23 00:39:14.840: D/StorageManagerService(3655): getExternalStorageMountMode : final mountMode=1, uid : 10821, packageName : com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:14.840: I/ApplicationPolicy(3655): isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:com.awesomeproject user:0
10-23 00:39:14.840: D/ActivityManager(3655): package  com.awesomeproject, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
10-23 00:39:14.840: I/ApplicationPolicy(3655): isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.awesomeproject user:0
10-23 00:39:14.870: I/ActivityManager(3655): Start proc 22662:com.awesomeproject/u0a821 for activity com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity
10-23 00:39:14.877: I/SELinux(22662): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.awesomeproject 
10-23 00:39:14.953: I/ActivityManager(3655): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN typ=null flg=0x10200000 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity}} from uid 10068
10-23 00:39:14.956: D/ActivityManagerPerformance(3655): Received MSG_CFMS_HINT_AMS_SWITCH pkgName: com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:14.967: D/ViewRootImpl@1d7ab40[awesomeproject](3655): setView = DecorView@d5d3be[awesomeproject] TM=true MM=false
10-23 00:39:14.967: D/ViewRootImpl@1d7ab40[awesomeproject](3655): setView = DecorView@d5d3be[awesomeproject] TM=true MM=false
10-23 00:39:14.971: I/ActivityManager(3655): DSS on for com.awesomeproject and scale is 1.0
10-23 00:39:14.973: V/WindowManager(3655): Relayout Window{2819a79 u0 Splash Screen com.awesomeproject}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x1848 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#20 ty=3 fl=#81830118 pfl=0x20011 wanim=0x10302fd vsysui=0x600 needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0 naviIconColor=0}
10-23 00:39:14.975: I/SurfaceFlinger(3197): id=592 createSurf (1080x1920),1 flag=404, Splash Screen com.awesomeproject#0
10-23 00:39:15.001: V/WindowManager(3655): finishDrawingLocked: mDrawState=COMMIT_DRAW_PENDING Window{2819a79 u0 Splash Screen com.awesomeproject} in Surface(name=Splash Screen com.awesomeproject)
10-23 00:39:15.002: D/ActivityManager(3655): applyOptionsLocked, ANIM_CUSTOM_SCALE_UP, task.getRootActivity() : ActivityRecord{6b7a94b u0 com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity t9606}, task.getTaskToReturnTo() : 1
10-23 00:39:15.010: D/GameManagerService(3655): handleForegroundChange(). pkgName: com.awesomeproject, clsName: com.awesomeproject.MainActivity,FgActivityName:com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity
10-23 00:39:15.011: D/GameManagerService(3655): notifyResumePause(). pkg: com.awesomeproject, type: 4, isMinimized: false, isTunableApp: false
10-23 00:39:15.011: D/MARsPolicyManager(3655): onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.awesomeproject, userId = 0
10-23 00:39:15.029: D/GamePkgDataHelper(3655): getGamePkgDataIncServer(). com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.029: D/GamePkgDataHelper(3655): getGamePkgDataIncServer(). com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.030: D/GameManagerService(3655): identifyGamePackage. com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.030: D/GamePkgDataHelper(3655): getGamePkgData(). com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.036: D/GamePkgDataHelper(3655): getGamePkgData(). com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.037: D/GameManagerService(3655): identifyGamePackage. com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.037: D/GamePkgDataHelper(3655): getGamePkgData(). com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.045: D/SoLoader(22662): adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
10-23 00:39:15.046: D/SoLoader(22662): adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.awesomeproject/lib-main flags = 1]
10-23 00:39:15.047: D/SoLoader(22662): Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
10-23 00:39:15.047: D/SoLoader(22662): Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.awesomeproject/lib-main flags = 1]
10-23 00:39:15.048: V/fb-UnpackingSoSource(22662): locked dso store /data/user/0/com.awesomeproject/lib-main
10-23 00:39:15.050: I/fb-UnpackingSoSource(22662): dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.awesomeproject/lib-main
10-23 00:39:15.050: V/fb-UnpackingSoSource(22662): releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.awesomeproject/lib-main
10-23 00:39:15.052: W/System.err(22662):    at com.awesomeproject.MainApplication.initializeFlipper(MainApplication.java:61)
10-23 00:39:15.052: W/System.err(22662):    at com.awesomeproject.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:46)
10-23 00:39:15.053: W/System.err(22662): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
10-23 00:39:15.056: D/GameManagerService(3655): identifyGamePackage. com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.056: D/GamePkgDataHelper(3655): getGamePkgData(). com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.061: D/GameManagerService(3655): identifyGamePackage. com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.061: D/GamePkgDataHelper(3655): getGamePkgData(). com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.061: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):        HWC | 7df8a2dcc0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |  112,  129,  828, 1402 | Splash Screen com.awesomeproject#0
10-23 00:39:15.090: D/SoLoader(22662): libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.awesomeproject/lib-main
10-23 00:39:15.090: D/SoLoader(22662): libjscexecutor.so found on /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64
10-23 00:39:15.140: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):       GLES | 7df8a2dcc0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |   27,   31, 1020, 1796 | Splash Screen com.awesomeproject#0
10-23 00:39:15.160: D/MdnieScenarioControlService(3655):  packageName : com.awesomeproject    className : com.awesomeproject.MainActivity
10-23 00:39:15.178: I/zygote64(22662): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
10-23 00:39:15.179: I/zygote64(22662): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
10-23 00:39:15.179: I/zygote64(22662): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
10-23 00:39:15.226: V/WindowManager(3655): Relayout Window{acc6470 u0 com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x1848 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#110 ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x10302fd vsysui=0x600 needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0 naviIconColor=0}
10-23 00:39:15.228: I/SurfaceFlinger(3197): id=593 createSurf (1080x1920),1 flag=404, com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity#0
10-23 00:39:15.242: D/libGLESv1(22662): STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:15.261: V/InputMethodManager(22662): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@3926903 nm : com.awesomeproject ic=null
10-23 00:39:15.262: V/InputMethodManagerService(3655): windowGainedFocus : reason=WINDOW_FOCUS_GAIN client=android.os.BinderProxy@927ec22 inputContext=null missingMethods= attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@e6b579c nm = com.awesomeproject controlFlags=#104 softInputMode=#110 windowFlags=#81810100
10-23 00:39:15.288: V/WindowManager(3655): finishDrawingLocked: mDrawState=COMMIT_DRAW_PENDING Window{acc6470 u0 com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity} in Surface(name=com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity)
10-23 00:39:15.293: D/InputEventReceiver(3655): channel '2819a79 Splash Screen com.awesomeproject (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
10-23 00:39:15.293: D/InputEventReceiver(3655): channel '2819a79 Splash Screen com.awesomeproject (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
10-23 00:39:15.309: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):        HWC | 7df8a2dcc0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0100 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |    0,    0, 1080, 1920 | Splash Screen com.awesomeproject#0
10-23 00:39:15.318: V/InputMethodManager(22662): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ca7d080 nm : com.awesomeproject ic=null
10-23 00:39:15.325: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):        HWC | 7df47fddc0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0100 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |    0,    0, 1080, 1920 | com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity#0
10-23 00:39:15.325: I/WindowManager(3655): Destroying surface Surface(name=Splash Screen com.awesomeproject) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2501 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:985 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurfaceUnchecked:3680 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroySurface:3628 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:722 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:706 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5335 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:550 
10-23 00:39:15.325: I/SurfaceFlinger(3197): id=592 Removed Splash Screen com.awesomeproject#0 (4/7)
10-23 00:39:15.331: I/SurfaceFlinger(3197): id=592 Removed Splash Screen com.awesomeproject#0 (-2/7)
10-23 00:39:15.337: I/Layer(3197): id=592 onRemoved Splash Screen com.awesomeproject#0 
10-23 00:39:15.345: I/ActivityManager(3655): Displayed com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity: +361ms
10-23 00:39:15.355: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):        HWC | 7df47fddc0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0100 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |    0,    0, 1080, 1920 | com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity#0
10-23 00:39:15.440: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):        HWC | 7df47fddc0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0100 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |    0,    0, 1080, 1920 | com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity#0
10-23 00:39:15.440: D/SoLoader(22662): libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.awesomeproject/lib-main
10-23 00:39:15.440: D/SoLoader(22662): libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64
10-23 00:39:15.443: D/SoLoader(22662): libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.awesomeproject/lib-main
10-23 00:39:15.443: D/SoLoader(22662): libfb.so found on /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64
10-23 00:39:15.444: D/SoLoader(22662): libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.awesomeproject/lib-main
10-23 00:39:15.444: D/SoLoader(22662): libfb.so found on /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64
10-23 00:39:15.444: I/zygote64(22662): Thread[24,tid=22718,Native,Thread*=0x7cfc286e00,peer=0x12fd5a20,"create_react_context"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64/libfb.so"
10-23 00:39:15.489: D/MdnieScenarioControlService(3655):  packageName : com.awesomeproject    className : com.awesomeproject.MainActivity
10-23 00:39:15.629: D/SoLoader(22662): libyoga.so not found on /data/data/com.awesomeproject/lib-main
10-23 00:39:15.630: D/SoLoader(22662): libyoga.so found on /data/app/com.awesomeproject-EThs6uZ8OF5VI7aipjsTOg==/lib/arm64
10-23 00:39:16.055: A/DEBUG(22734): pid: 22662, tid: 22721, name: mqt_native_modu  >>> com.awesomeproject <<<
10-23 00:39:17.162: W/ActivityManager(3655): crash : com.awesomeproject,0
10-23 00:39:17.163: W/ActivityManager(3655):   Force finishing activity com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity
10-23 00:39:17.165: W/MultiScreenManagerService(3655): moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): root activity or app is null, task=TaskRecord{9d01df6d0 #9606 A=com.awesomeproject U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}, rootActivity=null
10-23 00:39:17.173: I/ActivityManager(3655): Showing crash dialog for package com.awesomeproject u0
10-23 00:39:17.222: D/ViewRootImpl@21c7092[awesomeproject](3655): setView = DecorView@f14f719[awesomeproject] TM=true MM=false
10-23 00:39:17.241: V/WindowManager(3655): Relayout Window{da21660 u0 Application Error: com.awesomeproject}: viewVisibility=0 req=1015x442 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=#11 sim=#120 ty=2003 fl=#1820002 pfl=0x110 fmt=-3 wanim=0x10302ec surfaceInsets=Rect(6, 6 - 6, 6) needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0 naviIconColor=0}
10-23 00:39:17.244: I/SurfaceFlinger(3197): id=595 createSurf (1027x454),1 flag=4, Application Error: com.awesomeproject#0
10-23 00:39:17.273: I/WindowManager(3655): WIN DEATH: Window{acc6470 u0 com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity}
10-23 00:39:17.274: I/WindowManager(3655): Destroying surface Surface(name=com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2501 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:985 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeImmediately:2404 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2606 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.-wrap1:0 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:3151 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:843 <bottom of call stack> 
10-23 00:39:17.278: I/SurfaceFlinger(3197): id=593 Removed com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity#0 (1/6)
10-23 00:39:17.278: I/SurfaceFlinger(3197): id=593 Removed com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity#0 (-2/6)
10-23 00:39:17.282: I/ActivityManager(3655): Process com.awesomeproject (pid 22662) has died: vis  +99TOP (133,1567)
10-23 00:39:17.285: V/WindowManager(3655): finishDrawingLocked: mDrawState=COMMIT_DRAW_PENDING Window{da21660 u0 Application Error: com.awesomeproject} in Surface(name=Application Error: com.awesomeproject)
10-23 00:39:17.286: I/SurfaceFlinger(3197): id=593 Removed com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity#0 (-2/6)
10-23 00:39:17.289: I/Layer(3197): id=593 onRemoved com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity#0 
10-23 00:39:17.326: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):       GLES | 7df0377180 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1027.0,  454.0 |   68,  787, 1010, 1204 | Application Error: com.awesomeproject#0
10-23 00:39:17.334: D/PackageManager(3655): getComponentMetadataForIconTray : com.awesomeproject.MainActivity does not exist in mServices
10-23 00:39:17.334: D/PackageManager(3655): getComponentMetadataForIconTray : com.awesomeproject.MainActivity does not exist in mProviders
10-23 00:39:17.334: D/PackageManager(3655): getComponentMetadataForIconTray : com.awesomeproject.MainActivity does not exist in mReceivers
10-23 00:39:17.335: D/ApplicationPackageManager(4073): updateItemMetaDataForFixedIconScale: package: com.awesomeproject
10-23 00:39:17.335: D/PackageManager(3655): getSelectedMetaData : packageName(com.awesomeproject) or Metadata strings {[Ljava.lang.String;@a4708a8}
10-23 00:39:17.336: I/ApplicationPackageManager(4073): load=com.awesomeproject, bg=144-144, dr=144-144, forDefault=true, density=0
10-23 00:39:17.338: I/ApplicationPackageManager(4073): load=com.awesomeproject-crop, bg=114-114, dr=144-144
10-23 00:39:17.341: W/PkgUtils(17655): p: com.awesomeproject, u:0
10-23 00:39:17.358: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):       GLES | 7df0377180 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1027.0,  454.0 |   48,  778, 1031, 1213 | Application Error: com.awesomeproject#0
10-23 00:39:17.452: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):    22,  767, 1058, 1225 | Application Error: com.awesomeproject#0
10-23 00:39:17.460: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197):        HWC | 7df0377180 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1027.0,  454.0 |   20,  767, 1058, 1226 | Application Error: com.awesomeproject#0
10-23 00:39:21.455: D/SurfaceFlinger(3197): 5 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1027.0,  454.0 |   26,  769, 1053, 1223 | Application Error: com.awesomeproject#0
```

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.awesomeproject"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Comment: could you show the android studio log error info when the app crashs

Comment: Did you allow developer mode debugging in the settings of the actual Samsung phone?

Comment: What do you mean by android studio log? If you mean logcat, it is already posted.

Comment: Yes developer mode debugging is active. I am testing android projects with my phone for more than 2 years.

Comment: I just ran the app on another real device with android 9 and it works fine. So why this doesn't run on android 8?

Comment: I think the problem is related to metro bundler. I tried to create bundle file manually and buid apk and app works fine. But if I run app in a normal way(with metro bundler) it will crashe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after struggling more than 2 days on this problem I found the solution. I checked every single line of logcat and comprised it with release mode logs. I found these logs are only printed when the app crashes:

```
2019-10-23 16:55:21.774 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
2019-10-23 16:55:21.775 3655-3796/? D/MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.awesomeproject    className : com.awesomeproject.MainActivity
2019-10-23 16:55:21.782 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.783 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.787 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.788 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.790 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.791 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.793 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.checkbox.ReactCheckBoxManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.802 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.813 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.818 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.823 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.826 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.835 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollContainerViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.837 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.839 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.842 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.849 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.852 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.854 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.857 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.859 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.864 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.865 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.868 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.869 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.873 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.878 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.880 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ModalHostShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.882 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.883 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.884 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.895 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.902 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.906 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode
2019-10-23 16:55:21.908 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.915 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.918 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
2019-10-23 16:55:21.918 17844-17896/com.awesomeproject W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextShadowNode
```

Based on some research I found that the problem is about google play services. I updated it to the last version and now the problem completely solved.